# Can ping but not browse; does not appear to be DNS nor proxy issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I can't connect to the internet.

This problem happens to me once every week or so, with no regular pattern. The disconnection can happen whether i'm using the computer at the time or not.
It can be easily fixed by restarting or relogging, but I'd like to find the cause.

The laptop is connected wirelessly to a router.
My laptop is the only computer on the network affected in this way.
Turning off my firewall and switching to a different wireless adapter does not seem to help.

Window's troubleshooter says nothing is wrong. Reconnecting/disconnecting does not help.
Right after I reset the adapter, it seems as if I can connect for a brief second or two before it goes back to not working.

My irc client did not disconnect until I switched adapters. Then it disconnected and stayed disconnected.
Many times, chrome will stop working first, followed a few minutes later by irc.

I can ping google, and plenty of other sites just fine.

```
Pinging google.com [167.206.252.98] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 167.206.252.98: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=59
Reply from 167.206.252.98: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=59
Reply from 167.206.252.98: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=59
Reply from 167.206.252.98: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=59

Ping statistics for 167.206.252.98:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 19ms, Average = 17ms
```

I've tried all my browsers (chrome, firefox, tor, lynx), and none of them can reach either google.com nor 167.206.252.98

tracert gives me a timeout somewhere in the chain of hops. This also happens when the internet is working. Not sure if it's normal.

Google:
    Tracing route to google.com [167.206.145.50]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  1     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  openrg.home [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    39 ms    11 ms    11 ms  433be071.cst.lightpath.net [67.59.224.113]
  4    14 ms    15 ms    14 ms  ool-4353fb89.dyn.optonline.net [67.83.251.137]
  5    11 ms    14 ms    14 ms  64.15.6.110
  6    43 ms    27 ms    15 ms  167.206.145.50
```

Trace complete.

Yahoo:
    Tracing route to yahoo.com [206.190.36.45]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
  1     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  openrg.home [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    11 ms    12 ms    12 ms  433be071.cst.lightpath.net [67.59.224.113]
  4    14 ms    14 ms    14 ms  ool-4353fb89.dyn.optonline.net [67.83.251.137]
  5    12 ms    41 ms    14 ms  64.15.7.41
  6    22 ms    17 ms    53 ms  451be0ea.cst.lightpath.net [65.19.120.234]
  7    24 ms    20 ms    21 ms  rtr7-ge2-1.in.nycmnyzr.cv.net [64.15.0.106]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    22 ms    21 ms    22 ms  ae-6.pat1.dcp.yahoo.com [216.115.102.174]
 10    48 ms    60 ms    51 ms  ae-4.pat1.che.yahoo.com [216.115.101.153]
 11    67 ms    71 ms    75 ms  ae-8.pat2.dnx.yahoo.com [216.115.96.121]
 12    99 ms   134 ms   105 ms  ae-8.pat1.gqb.yahoo.com [216.115.96.122]
 13   164 ms    95 ms   113 ms  ae-0.msr1.gq1.yahoo.com [66.196.67.1]
 14   100 ms   127 ms   127 ms  xe-2-3-1.clr1-a-gdc.gq1.yahoo.com [67.195.1.179]

 15   117 ms   101 ms   104 ms  et-18-1.fab6-1-gdc.gq1.yahoo.com [67.195.1.239]

 16   111 ms   110 ms   109 ms  po-14.bas2-7-prd.gq1.yahoo.com [206.190.32.39]
 17   111 ms    95 ms    97 ms  ir1.fp.vip.gq1.yahoo.com [206.190.36.45]
```

Trace complete.

The same results appear from a virtual machine on the laptop.

Under LAN settings, I do NOT have a proxy enabled.
Disabling my other adapters (hamachi) did not help.

netsh winsock reset was also run before and after the problem, but had no effect. Apparently I have to restart before it takes effect, but since restarting already fixes the problem, it doesn't help.

I've heard that it might be a DNS issue but the fact that i was unable to connect to 167.206.252.98 seems to spoil that theory
I've also heard that it might be a system wide proxy, but I did not find any such proxy in window's settings

Malwarebytes scan did not find anything.

I also checked the hosts.ini file, but everything was commented out.

A quick google reveals a lot of thread on this, most of which are resolved as DNS or proxy problems, but neither of those seem to be the case here, and this case seems to be different in that the connection problem only happens sporadically.

Might anyone know the issue?

Comment: `This problem happens to me once every week or so, with no regular pattern` - Once a week or so is in fact a regular pattern.

Comment: Sometimes the occurrences are seperated by months, and sometimes by days, but it doesn't happen every Friday or something.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In fact, a lot of people I know have this particular problem. Window 8/8.1 has a lot of connectivity issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two years later, I've finally figured it out -- during one of these connectivity episodes, I tried to ssh into another machine and got the error

```
Network Error: no buffer space available
```

Which lead me to this question/answer :
https://serverfault.com/a/616474

And it turns out that killing and restarting explorer.exe fixes the problem.